# How to queue incoming PHP posts

Tags: php, post

### My Question

I want to queue incoming PHP posts,
i have a android app to post some data to server. Sometimes i must post data multiple times, but i want my first post must complete, after that my second post must proccess. How can i do this?

- *i don't use any framework, just pure php* *

### My tries

- I have recorded the transmission time when the first data is received. When the second post arrives, run the code again if there is not 5 seconds difference between first post and second post.

Comment: Just an idea: In your android app, generate a unique ID for each post, and when you send the same post multiple times to the server, you can see from the ID, if it is the same post or a new one.

Comment: @Wulf thats good idea but, if my second post complete earlier than my first post this is failing. Because there are more database operations in the first submission. So my second post must wait the first post complete. I don't want add like sleep(), wait() functions before posting second post.

Comment: Then what about waiting in your android app for the server to finish the first request, and after that sending the second post? You could also let your second request return 404 if the given ID is not yet in your database, so your android app knows, it has to send the request again (perhaps there with a little sleep).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution at [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) for syncing php processing.